# Javascript Get the common elements of three arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, intersection

I am trying to filter the common elements of 3 arrays. But instead of getting the common elements of 3 arrays, it only reads the 2 arrays and not the 3rd array. Here is my code, thank you:

```
function commonElementsOfArray(arr1, arr2, arr3) {
    return arr1.filter(function (n) {
        return arr2.indexOf(n) !== -1;
        return arr3.indexOf(n) !== -1;
    });
}
```

Comment: You have a function with two `return` statements. Just combine the two condition and only use one `return`. Here is an example: `return arr2.indexOf(n) !== -1 && arr3.indexOf(n) !== -1`

Comment: @ejade ... Regarding all the provided answers / solutions / approaches are there any questions left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @Titus, the issue in your code is the double `return` statements - once the first `return` is found the filter function will exit.

However, there is also an issue worth pointing out in your approach to finding common elements regarding `Array.indexOf`. The problem is that `Array.indexOf` is an `O(n)` operation, meaning the parameter will be checked against every element of arr2 and every element of arr3. On face value that sounds like the right approach, but if the arrays are large then this will be a very slow function. For instance, if each array has 1,000 entries (n) then your function will take each element and compare against everything in arr2 and arr3, resulting in thousands of operations per element (`O(n^2)` time complexity).

One alternative is to create a `Map` and populate it as you iterate through each array to track the number of times an entry has been seen. Finding values now has `O(1)` runtime. There is still the cost of iterating through each array which yields `O(n)` but because of the fast lookup this becomes `n * 1` operations or `O(n)` time complexity.

```js
function commonElementsOfArray(...arrays) {
  const size = arrays.length;
  const map = new Map();
  
  arrays.forEach(arr => {
    arr.forEach(entry => {
      if (!map.has(entry)) {
        map.set(entry, 1);
      } else {
        let timesSeen = map.get(entry);
        map.set(entry, ++timesSeen);
      }
    });
  });

  const commonElements = [];
  map.forEach((count, key) => {
    if (count === size) {
      commonElements.push(key);
    }
  });

  return commonElements;
}

console.log(commonElementsOfArray([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [2, 4, 5]));
```

Answer (score 3):

How about refactoring the OP's code into a generic intersection functionality which implements a simplified intersection function of two arrays and generates the overall intersection of more than 2 arrays by a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) task which processes the generic function's (array type) arguments?

Thus the intersection of two arrays would be based on the OP's code [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) approach but using [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) instead of [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). Something like ...

```
function getIntersectionOfTwo(a, b) {
  return a.filter(function (n) {
    return b.includes(n);
  });
}
```

A generic `getIntersection` then just needs to assure the type safety of its arguments and the correct return value for too less arguments as well as the intersection result for the minimum amount of correctly provided arguments ...

```js
function getIntersection(...listOfArrays) {
  function getIntersectionOfTwo(a, b) {
    return a.filter(function (n) {
      return b.includes(n);
    });
  }
  // assure only array type arguments.
  listOfArrays = listOfArrays.filter(Array.isArray);

  return (listOfArrays[1] ?? listOfArrays[0])
    && listOfArrays.reduce(getIntersectionOfTwo);   
}

console.log(
  'getIntersection() ...',
  getIntersection()
);
console.log(
  'getIntersection(9, "foo", 0) ...',
  getIntersection(9, "foo", 0)
);
console.log(
  'getIntersection([2, 7, 0], "bar") ...',
  getIntersection([2, 7, 0], "bar")
);
console.log(
  'getIntersection([2, 7, 0, 4], [6, 2, 7, 3]) ...',
  getIntersection([2, 7, 0, 4], [6, 2, 7, 3])
);
console.log(
  'getIntersection([2, 7, 0, 4], [6, 2, 7, 3], [9, 1, 2]) ...',
  getIntersection([2, 7, 0, 4], [6, 2, 7, 3], [9, 1, 2])
);
console.log(
  'getIntersection([2, 7, 0, 4], [6, 2, 7, 3], [9]) ...',
  getIntersection([2, 7, 0, 4], [6, 2, 7, 3], [9])
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

The above example's implementation of `getIntersectionOfTwo` of cause is kept simple for a better understanding of the overall task's refactoring process.

Within a next refactoring step this function could be improved too in order to handle/process vast array data more efficiently. Thus one would use within the `filter` callback a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) based lookup instead of searching within each `filter` iteration whether `b.includes(n)`.

```js
function getIntersection(...listOfArrays) {
  function getIntersectionOfTwo(intersection, iterableItem) {
    // in order to compare huge arrays more efficiently access ...
    const [

      comparisonBase, // ... the shorter one as comparison base
      comparisonList, // ... and the longer one to filter from.

    ] = [intersection, iterableItem]
      .sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length);

    // create a `Map` based lookup table from the shorter array.
    const itemLookup = comparisonBase
      .reduce((map, item) => map.set(item, true), new Map)

    // the intersection is the result of following filter task.
    return comparisonList.filter(item => itemLookup.has(item));
  }
  // assure only array type arguments.
  listOfArrays = listOfArrays.filter(Array.isArray);

  return (listOfArrays[1] ?? listOfArrays[0])
    && listOfArrays.reduce(getIntersectionOfTwo);   
}

console.log(
  'getIntersection() ...',
  getIntersection(),
);
console.log(
  'getIntersection(9, "foo", 0) ...',
  getIntersection(9, "foo", 0),
);
console.log(
  'getIntersection([2, 7, 0], "bar") ...',
  getIntersection([2, 7, 0], "bar"),
);
console.log(
  'getIntersection([2, 7, 0, 4], [6, 2, 7, 3]) ...',
  getIntersection([2, 7, 0, 4], [6, 2, 7, 3]),
);
console.log(
  'getIntersection([2, 7, 0, 4], [6, 2, 7, 3], [9, 1, 2]) ...',
  getIntersection([2, 7, 0, 4], [6, 2, 7, 3], [9, 1, 2]),
);
console.log(
  'getIntersection([2, 7, 0, 4], [6, 2, 7, 3], [9]) ...',
  getIntersection([2, 7, 0, 4], [6, 2, 7, 3], [9]),
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```